# Does Scintilla need a directive? I keep getting an error?

Tags: c#, scintilla

So, when I drag in Scintilla to my C# form, and try to run it, I get the error:

> The type or namespace name
>   'ScintillaNet' could not be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)

The error appears to be coming from the designer for Form1.

I also get the warning (but not error):

> The referenced assembly "ScintillaNet"
>   could not be resolved because it has a
>   dependency on "System.Design,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which
>   is not in the currently targeted
>   framework
>   ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client".
>   Please remove references to assemblies
>   not in the targeted framework or
>   consider retargeting your project.

So, I can't run my program...

What's wrong, and how do I fix it? I've installed scintilla just like how the directions for it suggested...

Comment: Have you tried adding a reference to System.Design?

Answer (score 3):

I was also experiencing this error (although I am hosting in WPF not WinForms).  It was caused by Visual Studio 2010 defaulting the project to .Net 4.0 Client profile rather than the full .Net 4.0 profile.